# FastAPI redirection for trailing slash returns non-ssl link

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, uvicorn

Running into an issue when we call an endpoint and a redirect occurs due to a missing trailing slash. As you can see in the image below, when a request is made to **https**://.../notifications, the FastAPI server responds with a redirect to **http**://...notifications/

I suspect that it's an app configuration issue rather than a server configuration issue. Does anyone have an idea of how to resolve this issue?

[image: example of redirect]

Comment: In your code, do you use @app.get("notifications") or @app.get("notifications/") ? Also, have you tried https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/middleware/#httpsredirectmiddleware maybe it helps setting the https response

Comment: It seemed like the HTTPSRedirect wouldn't solve the issue as the incoming request was in the correct schema. The way I understood the documentation was to provide the functionality: http (incoming request) -> https (redirected request). This seems to be https (incoming request) -> http (redirected request). Perhaps I'm misguided, though, so I'm testing right now...

Comment: The redirect could be due to difference in path (the @app.get stuff) and the requested path. Do you mind sharing the code of the handling function and the one for performing the request?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem? I'm having the problem right now as well. This issue might be relevant but adding the "--prefix-headers" to the uvicorn call didn't resolve the issue for me. https://github.com/encode/starlette/issues/538

Comment: Are you guys running your server behind a reverse proxy? @Ben

Comment: @gustavo-kawamoto yes we are

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is because your application isn't trusting the reverse proxy's headers overriding the scheme (the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header that's passed when it handles a TLS request).

There's a few ways we can fix that:

- If you're running the application straight from `uvicorn` server, try using the flag `--forwarded-allow-ips '*'`.
- If you're running `gunicorn` you can set as well the flag `--forwarded-allow-ips="*"`.
- In either application, you can additionally use the `FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS` environment variable.

**Important:** the `*` should be used only as a test, as it'll lead your application to trust the `X-Forwarded-*` headers from any source. I suggest you read [uvicorn's docs](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#http) and [gunicorn's docs](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html#nginx-configuration) for a deeper knowledge of what to set in this flag and why.

Answer (score 4):

I experienced this issue when using FastAPI with react-admin.

One workaround is to change FastAPI app so it doesn't make redirects, but treats both URLs as valid API endpoints (with and without slash).

You can use this snippet wrote by [malthunayan](https://github.com/malthunayan) to change behaviour of `APIRouter`:

```py
from typing import Any, Callable

from fastapi import APIRouter as FastAPIRouter
from fastapi.types import DecoratedCallable


class APIRouter(FastAPIRouter):
    def api_route(
        self, path: str, *, include_in_schema: bool = True, **kwargs: Any
    ) -> Callable[[DecoratedCallable], DecoratedCallable]:
        if path.endswith("/"):
            path = path[:-1]

        add_path = super().api_route(
            path, include_in_schema=include_in_schema, **kwargs
        )

        alternate_path = path + "/"
        add_alternate_path = super().api_route(
            alternate_path, include_in_schema=False, **kwargs
        )

        def decorator(func: DecoratedCallable) -> DecoratedCallable:
            add_alternate_path(func)
            return add_path(func)

        return decorator
```

source: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2060#issuecomment-834868906

(you can also see other similar solutions in this GitHub issue)

---

Another workaround is to add:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">
```

to `index.html` file in frontend. It will upgrade all requests from `http` to `https` (also when run locally, so it may not be the best workaround)

Comment: the meta tag solved it for me using FastAPI and Uvicron.

Answer (score 2):

The older answers helped me to isolate the issue, but I was not happy to solve the challenge at the infrastucture level. **I wanted to be able to cover the expected behaviour by automated tests within my software project**. Read my blog post [for more details, why I prefer the solution described below](https://www.timorieber.de/master-fastapi-endpoint-urls-behind-a-nginx-reverse-proxy/).

Since [FastAPI version 0.98.0](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/pt/release-notes/#0980) the framework provides a way to disable the redirect behaviour by setting the `redirect_slashes` parameter to `False`, which is `True` by default. This works [for the whole application](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/pt/reference/fastapi/) as well as [for individual routers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/pt/reference/apirouter/).

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter


healthcheck_router = APIRouter(redirect_slashes=False)


@healthcheck_router.get('/')
async def healtcheck() -> dict:
    return {'state': 'healthy'}


def create_app() -> FastAPI:
    app = FastAPI(redirect_slashes=False)
    return app.include_router(healthcheck_router, prefix='/api/health')
```

This change can also be tested easily:

```py
import pytest
from starlette.testclient import TestClient

from app import create_app


@pytest.fixture
def test_client() -> TestClient:
    app = create_app()
    return TestClient(app=app)


def test_healthcheck_returns_200(test_client: TestClient):
    response = test_client.get('/api/health/')

    assert response.status_code == 200


def test_healthcheck_without_trailing_slash_returns_404(test_client: TestClient):
    response = test_client.get('/api/health')

    assert response.status_code == 404
```

Comment: Can you add more info on why you preferred changing that on FastAPI instead of gunicorn/uvicorn? It's good practice to add reasons and then link, as links might die and leave the answer stranded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I included _my_ main reason in the answer. But I think the main value here is to add this important alternative (including code snippets, tests and links to the relevant docs) to the mix, to allow others make their own informed decision.

Comment: Thanks for adding it! It's also super fine to add links to enrich your point, just wanted to make sure the answer I wanted to upvote wouldn't go down the drain if anything happened to the link ;)

Comment: Agreed with you. Strict behavior looks better. But in our team we decide to  use endpoints without trailing slashes. What is your agrument to use trailing slash everywhere?

Comment: @broomrider: we don't use trailing slashes, too, but this answer and my blog post align with the official docs. "Slash or not to slash" is another more opinionated topic ;)

Answer (score 0):

I modified Karol Zlot's frontend workaround so that it's only applied in production. I added this to my main.ts file and it works great!

```
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  const meta = document.createElement('meta');
  meta.httpEquiv = "Content-Security-Policy";
  meta.content="upgrade-insecure-requests";
  document.head.appendChild(meta);
}
```