# How to determine forwarded-allow-ips for uvicorn server from docker network

Tags: docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I use Traefik as proxy and also have react frotend and fastAPI as backend. My backend is publicly exposed. The problem is unvicorn server redirects you from non trailing slash to url with a slash https://api.mydomain.com/posts -> http://api.mydomain.com/posts/ but it doesn't work for ssl. So, I'm getting errors in frontend about CORS and mixing content. Based on this topic [FastAPI redirection for trailing slash returns non-ssl link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511413/fastapi-redirection-for-trailing-slash-returns-non-ssl-link) I added --forwarded-allow-ips="*" to uvicorn server and now ssl redirection works, but as I understand it's not secure. I tried to add --forwarded-allow-ips="mydomain.com" but it doesn't work, I have no idea why as "mydomain.com" is an ip of the server so then ip of my proxy. I assume that's because my api get proxy IP from docker network, don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Wow, long time without answers. I have similar situation, but using nginx web server in a docker container and the web app in another container.

Comment: I fixed issue using static IP for traefik container, and added it into forwarded-allow-ips. Not sure if this approach is a good enough

Comment: Wow, I didn't know any traefik project. It looks amazing. Anyhow, I'm sure it can be done with NGINX and uvicorn

Answer (score 1):

If you're positive that the Uvicorn/Gunicorn server is only ever accessible via an internal IP (is completely firewalled from the external network  such that all connections come from a trusted proxy [[*ref*]](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html)), then it would be okay to use `--forwarded-allow-ips="*"`.

However, I believe the answer to your original question would be to inspect your Docker container(s) and grab their IPs. Since traefik is routing/proxying requests, you probably just need to grab the traefik container ID and run an inspect:

```
~$ docker ps`

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                                                      NAMES
ids_here   traefik:v2.3                    "/entrypoint.sh --pr…"   1 second ago     Up 1 second     0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   traefik


~$ docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' ids_here
 172.18.0.1
```

Try whitelisting that IP.

From what I've read, it is not possible to whitelist a subnet inside `--forwarded-allow-ips="x"`. If your server re-starts, your container's internal IPs are subject (likely) to change. A hack-ish fix for this would be forcing the container start order using `depends_on`. The `depends_on` container will start first and have a lower/first IP assignment.

However, it is possible in Docker like this [*[ref](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.0/middlewares/ipwhitelist/)*]:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.testIPwhitelist.ipwhitelist.sourcerange=127.0.0.1/32, 192.168.1.7"
  - "traefik.http.middlewares.testIPwhitelist.ipwhitelist.ipstrategy.depth=2"
```