# unable to confirm subscribing to HTTP\S endpoint from AWS SNS using python?

Tags: python, amazon-sns, fastapi

I am using python fastApi as a framework, I have the following post method:

```
async def post(request:Request):
    logger.info(f"recieve a sns notification {request}")
    return {"message": f"got message {await request.body()} "}
```

I am aware that in the above method there is no logic to confirm it is just a showcase for my real issue

I subscribed the endpoint through the console, and the status is `Pending confirmation`

every time press the "Request Confirmation" button I can see in cloudWatch logger:

```
"POST /api/customer-profiles HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
```

when I use the following code from my local machine:

```
import requests
import boto3
import json

url = "https://<my-domain>/api/customer-profiles"
payload = {"a": {"a":"v"}}
res = requests.post(url=url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

the response:

```
<Response [200]>
```

with content

```
b'{"message":"got message b\'{\\"a\\": {\\"a\\": \\"v\\"}}\' "}'
```

in cloud watch is can also see:

```
INFO:     <ip> - "POST /api/customer-profiles HTTP/1.1" 307 Temporary Redirect
#logger wirtes!!
recieve a sns notification <starlette.requests.Request object at 0x7ff459d50610>
INFO:     <ip> - "POST /api/customer-profiles/ HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

I Am not sure what i am doing wrong
The endpoints is working (also all test are good) but only for the SNS confirmation its **NOT**,

what am I doing wrong? why the endpoint never get the request?

Answer (score 1):

its all come to a "/"
[see the following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63511413/fastapi-redirection-for-trailing-slash-returns-non-ssl-link)
fastapi make the redirect between `www.example.com/api` to `www.exmaple.com/api/` there is a location redirect between the tow.
once I wrote the subscriber HTTP in the SNS with a \ all was solved.